# How to turn a number into a date snowflake

Tags: date, type-conversion, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that displays as

| ID | END_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 20,300,615 |
| 99 | 20,510,315 |
| 12 | 20,500,415 |

The end date column is of type NUMBER(38,0) and I need to turn it into a date with format 'YYYY-MM-DD' and then convert that to a string.

I tried doing

```
SELECT *, TO_VARCHAR(TO_DATE(END_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) AS CONVERTED_DATE
FROM MY TABLE
```

but I am getting an error saying

```
Can't parse '20300615' as date with format 'YYYY-MM-DD'
```

Is there another way I can achieve this? I also tried

```
SELECT *, TO_DATE(TO_VARCHAR(END_DATE), 'YYYY-MM-DD) AS CONVERTED_DATE
FROM MY TABLE
```

which gave the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select to_char(to_date(to_char(end_date),'yyyymmdd'),’yyyy-mm-dd’)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33941694)

Comment: Updated the answer to return a string in the required format

Answer (score 0):

You can cast, the number to a string/text, and then parse that string, or do some integer math, and use date_from_part

I believe the later will perform better over larger datasets.

```
with data(id, end_date) as (
    select * from values
    (12,    20300615),
    (99,    20510315),
    (12,    20500415)
)
select
    id, 
    end_date,
    try_to_date(end_date::text, 'yyyymmdd') as date1,
    try_to_date(to_char(end_date), 'yyyymmdd') as date2,
    date_from_parts(end_date/10000, (end_date/100)%100, end_date%100 ) as date3
from data;
```

| ID | END_DATE | DATE1 | DATE2 | DATE3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 20,300,615 | 2030-06-15 | 2030-06-15 | 2030-06-15 |
| 99 | 20,510,315 | 2051-03-15 | 2051-03-15 | 2051-03-15 |
| 12 | 20,500,415 | 2050-04-15 | 2050-04-15 | 2050-04-15 |

```
create table seq_of_numbers as select seq8() as num from table(generator(rowcount=>10000000));

-- prime local date cache
select 2 * num * num from seq_of_numbers;
-- 6.2s

select try_to_date(num::text, 'yyyymmdd') as date1 from seq_of_numbers;
-- 4.0s

select   date_from_parts(num/10000, (num/100)%100, num%100 ) as date3 from seq_of_numbers;
-- 3.2s
```